# Does this "normalized" measure of gaussianity work?

Tags: normal-distribution, nonparametric, entropy

For a side project, I need some measure of gaussianity of a probability density, such that by optimizing to maximize the measure, I optimize for the density to become gaussian-shaped.

Typically you can do this using negentropy, but the problem is the variance of the optimized probability density is not set beforehand - all that I desire is gaussianity, and that may require a certain variance, not predetermined. Thus I don't think negentropy would work as a consistent measure - it may be, for example, that a less-gaussian-shaped distribution wins out over a more-gaussian-shaped-distribution simply because its possible to trade off variance and gaussianity in such a way to improve negentropy while not increasing or even decreasing gaussianity.

The idea I had is: since the gaussian entropy (maximum differential entropy for fixed variance) is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e) + \ln(\sigma)$, that maybe I could just subtract out the variance and use "adjusted/normalized entropy" as a nonparametric measure of gaussianity:

$$H(p) - \ln(\sigma(p))$$

where $H$ is entropy.

Has this been done before? Does anyone see an issue with this approach?

Comment: Are you truly interested in the density or is it the "Gaussianity" of the *distribution function* that actually matters?

Comment: I'll tell you exactly the use case: I want to see what happens if I try to fit a curve by using, as an objective function, the gaussianity of the resulting residuals. So it is really the gaussianity of the distribution function that matters. Ideally I'd have a robust measure that works for a set of discrete points, in the absence of that I'm trying measures on the kernel density estimate.

Comment: The distinction is this: the empirical distribution of the residuals doesn't even have a density function!  Your KDE contains a load of artifactual information in the form of the kernel itself--and the proposal to use entropy is going to be highly sensitive to the kernel. Thus you truly do want to focus on the distribution function and not any density derived from it. Note, too, that (unless you are fitting using a GLM or something like it) the *only* way in which you are able to modify the conditional distribution of the response is by recentering it.

Comment: I agree, it would be highly preferable to go straight to the distribution function, and KDE may be too noisy to work. 


The last part isn't right - it's nonlinear regression so I can modify the residual distribution freely. Actually that doesn't seem right even with a linear model, by modifying the slope the variance should change too, if Im visualizing things right.


Do you know of any robust gaussianity measures of an empirical distribution?

Comment: Whether the curve is linear or not is not terribly relevant. In the end, you're going to have a function that maps its parameters into some measure of "Gaussianity" of the residuals and you'll want to optimize that function. It's almost sure to come down to a numerical optimization, so what you want to be thinking about is why you're trying to do this, what "Gaussianity" of the collected residuals really means to you as a loss function, and whether the substantial increase in computational effort is going to buy you anything.

Comment: yes, this is almost definitely a numerical optimization problem. its mostly a curiosity - I want to see if its possible to prevent overfitting, without artificially limiting or putting a prior on the hypothesis space - if making the objective function be that we expect some error, rather than trying to minimize error, can "automatically" prevent overfitting by being a more realistic objective. I'm not sure what you mean when you say I cannot modify the conditional distribution of the response except recentering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60860/discussion-between-aabeshou-and-whuber).

Comment: If the measure of Gaussianity is any good, it's going to be smooth.  That implies it will be quadratic to second order relative to the best possible result.  It is therefore possible--perhaps even likely--that the usual method to minimize quadratic loss will do just fine: namely, nonlinear least squares. It's certainly a good thing to keep in mind for reasoning about what you're doing, because it suggests that this is not going to be an effective approach to overfitting.

Comment: "it's going to be smooth. That implies it will be quadratic to second order relative to the best possible result" can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: That's one implication of Taylor's theorem and the definition of "smooth" as being "highly differentiable" (in this case, at least second differentiable).

Comment: I understand that, I mean what do you mean by "relative to the best possible result"? Do you mean the taylor expansion would be done around the optimum? Your logic would seem to imply that any smooth objective should give the same result as least squares, which is of course wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's done around the optimum: that guarantees the linear term vanishes.  And no, I'm not asserting this will be equivalent to least squares, but I am arguing it is likely to satisfy many of the same properties. The analysis needs to continue by considering how your loss function departs from being quadratic for larger residuals.  That can lead to more *robust* fitting, but there doesn't seem to be much of a connection, if any, to *overfitting.*

Comment: the connection to overfitting in my mind comes from: consider a lot of points, and hypothesis space = smooth functions. then by simply minimizing squared residuals, we can arrive at total overfitting, a curve which goes through every single point. but if we optimize for the residuals following a gaussian distribution, then it would avoid that pathological overfitting. but now I'm realizing it may go there anyway, by going towards the "degenerate gaussian" at 0.. I'm also realizing it could go towards arbitrary gaussian distributions. So you're right this doesn't work even in theory

Comment: curve fitting based on any symmetric residual distribution doesn't do anything for overfitting, by the following counterexample: take any nice solution, C, and draw the curve that goes through, for each data point, the point the same distance away from it as C is, but on the other side. those two curves must look the same in the eyes of the objective function, but the second curve is a lot grosser

Comment: @whuber could you please say more about what in your intuition told you this doesnt have to do with overfitting?

Comment: It's not intuition--it's theory.  There are extensive theories about different loss functions and their effects, and (on the other hand) various theories about how to limit overfitting.  As a group--a "metatheory," if you like--they show that varying the loss function affects the robustness of the fits and what is being fit (such as a conditional expectation or conditional quantile) while *introducing a penalty for large parameters* causes regularization and shrinkage--that is, helps with overfitting.  Since you are proposing only the former and not the latter, the approach seems misguided.